# SQL Server : JOIN Returns Partial Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I'm joining 4 tables but during the join I'm only getting back about 45 phone numbers out of my 902 rows returned. I know that this is invalid and should have at least 500 or so rows with phone included. I'm missing something very simple in my join, I just can't seem to identify. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CUST.ACCOUNTNUM,
    PARTYTABLE.NAME,
    '' AS 'LEGAL NAME',
    --replace(replace(DIRPARTYPOSTALADDRESSVIEW.ADDRESS, char(13), ' '), char(10), ' ') AS 'ADDRESS',
    '' AS 'ADDRESS 2',
    '' AS 'ADDRESS 3',
    LOGISTICSADDRESS.STREET,
    LOGISTICSADDRESS.CITY,
    LOGISTICSADDRESS.STATE,
    LOGISTICSADDRESS.COUNTY,
    LOGISTICSADDRESS.ZIPCODE,
    LOGISTICSADDRESS.COUNTRYREGIONID AS 'COUNTRY',
      CASE
        WHEN electronicaddress.type = 1
        THEN electronicaddress.locator
        ELSE 'NULL'
        END AS 'Phone',
     CASE 
        WHEN electronicaddress.type = 4
        THEN electronicaddress.locator
        ELSE 'NULL'
        END AS 'Fax',
     CASE WHEN electronicaddress.type = 20
        THEN electronicaddress.locator
        ELSE 'NULL'
        END AS 'Email',
    CUST.SALESGROUP AS 'BROKER NAME',
    '' AS 'DISTRIBUTOR'
FROM 
    CUSTTABLE CUST
LEFT JOIN 
    DIRPARTYTABLE AS PARTYTABLE ON CUST.PARTY = PARTYTABLE.RECID
LEFT JOIN 
    DIRPARTYPOSTALADDRESSVIEW AS POSTALADDRESS ON PARTYTABLE.RECID = POSTALADDRESS.PARTY
LEFT JOIN 
    LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS AS LOGISTICSADDRESS ON LOGISTICSADDRESS.PRIVATEFORPARTY = PARTYTABLE.RECID 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS AS ELECTRONICADDRESS ON PARTYTABLE.RECID = ELECTRONICADDRESS.PRIVATEFORPARTY
-- modify below to show NOT LIKE (not like '%A/P' go get all ship-to) or LIKE (contains '%A/P%' to get bill-to)
WHERE 
    PARTYTABLE.NAME NOT LIKE '%A/P%'
ORDER BY 
    CUST.ACCOUNTNUM
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the filter to `ON` condition. Which is implicitly converting your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

```
........
LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE AS PARTYTABLE 
       ON CUST.PARTY = PARTYTABLE.RECID
      AND PARTYTABLE.NAME NOT LIKE '%A/P%'
........
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
FROM CUSTTABLE CUST
    LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE AS PARTYTABLE ON CUST.PARTY = PARTYTABLE.RECID
         AND PARTYTABLE.NAME NOT LIKE '%A/P%'
    LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYPOSTALADDRESSVIEW AS POSTALADDRESS ON PARTYTABLE.RECID = POSTALADDRESS.PARTY
    LEFT JOIN LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS AS LOGISTICSADDRESS ON LOGISTICSADDRESS.PRIVATEFORPARTY = PARTYTABLE.RECID 
    LEFT JOIN LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS AS ELECTRONICADDRESS ON PARTYTABLE.RECID = ELECTRONICADDRESS.PRIVATEFORPARTY
-- modify below to show NOT LIKE (not like '%A/P' go get all ship-to) or LIKE (contains '%A/P%' to get bill-to)
```